# I want to join data from two different tabs into one tab (in google sheet)

Tags: mysql, sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to join data from two different tabs of a single google sheet into one tab.

Lets say I have two tabs named, sheet1 and sheet2

Sheet1 data:

```
Month   value
aug     22
july    1
```

Sheet2 data:

```
Month   amount  count
aug     23      11
july    43      21
```

**I want this to be the result (in sheet3)** :

```
Month   amount  count   value
aug     23      11      22
july    43      21      1
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you provide a sample spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX({Sheet2!A:C, IFNA(VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A:A, Sheet1!A:B, 2, 0))})
```